# Visualización del formato de una variable de tipo float usando el formato IEEE754

Tags: c++, c

**Alguien me puede dar una idea o alguna fuente de internet para ayudarme a resolver este problema?**

Implemente un programa que solicite un número real, y usando operadores a nivel de bits pueda imprimir en pantalla los bits correspondientes al bit de signo, los bits del exponente y los bits de la mantisa. Por ejemplo:

Ingrese un número real: 2.5

01000000 00100000 00000000 00000000

bit de signo: 0 (0)
bits del exponente: 10000000 (128)
bits de la mantisa: 01000000000000000000000 (2097152)

Implemente funciones con los siguientes prototipos:

unsigned int get_ieee_exp (float)
unsigned int get_ieee_sign (float)
unsigned int get_ieee_mantissa (float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta respuesta sirve para punto flotante de 32 bits en una CPU little-endian (Intel y otras).

Bajo estas condiciones, el valor `2.5` aparece en memoria así:

```
00000000 00000000 00100000 01000000
```

Los bits de signo y exponente están al final de los 4 bytes.

Para obtener el signo hay que recuperar el último byte del valor y chequear si el bit superior está en cero o uno.

```
unsigned int get_ieee_sign(float valor) {
    unsigned char *signo = &valor;
    signo += sizeof (valor) - 1;
    return (*signo & 0x80) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Para recuperar el exponente de 8 bits hay que tomar siete bytes del último byte y agregarle el bit superior del penúltimo byte.

```
unsigned int get_ieee_exp(float valor) {
    unsigned char *exp = &valor;
    exp += sizeof (valor) - 1;
    unsigned char exponente = (*exp & 0x7F) << 1 | (*--exp & 0x80) >> 7;

    return (unsigned int) exponente;
}
```

La mantisa está compuesta de los 7 bits inferiores del penúltimo byte, concatenado con los bits de los restantes bytes.

```
unsigned int get_ieee_mantisa(float valor) {
    unsigned char *mant = &valor;
    mant += sizeof (valor) - 2;
    unsigned int mantisa = (*mant-- & 0x7F);
    for (int i = 2; i < sizeof (valor); i++) {
        mantisa = (mantisa << 8) + *mant--;
    }
    return mantisa;
}
```

**Comprobación**

```
void bit2char(unsigned char* bits, int size, unsigned char* out) {
    //  Recorrer todos los bytes de entrada
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned char value = *(bits + i);
        unsigned char mask = 0x80;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            *out = (mask & value) ? '1' : '0';
            out++;
            mask = mask >> 1;
        }
    }
    *out = 0;
}

void print_binary(char* linea) {
    while (*linea) {
        printf("%8.8s ", linea);
        linea += 8;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    float valor = -2.5;
    char linea[65];

    // Imprimir valor negativo para mostrar bit de signo.    
    bit2char(&valor, sizeof (valor), linea);
    print_binary(linea);

    // Usar valor positivo para resto de la prueba.
    valor = -valor;
    bit2char(&valor, sizeof (valor), linea);
    print_binary(linea);
    unsigned int signo = get_ieee_sign(valor);
    unsigned int exp = get_ieee_exp(valor);
    unsigned int mant = get_ieee_mantisa(valor);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", signo, exp, mant);
}
```

produce:

```
00000000 00000000 00100000 11000000 
00000000 00000000 00100000 01000000 
0 128 2097152
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora tengo otra duda como se resolveria el mismo ejercicio pero aplicando campos de bits?

Comment: @RaulFunes. Esa sería otra pregunta, con una respuesta diferente.